# Custom view in ListView disappears while scrolling in Android

Tags: java, android

I wrote a simple custom view for rows in ListView. It works fine, but when I try to scroll the list, I see only white rows without content. And when scrolling is over, rows continue to show again.

This is how I draw a custom view:

```
 @Override 
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
      if(poster != null) { 
           canvas.drawBitmap(poster, padding, padding, paint); 
      } 
      canvas.drawText(title, 55 + padding, 16 + padding, paint); 
 }
```

Maybe I missed something?

P.S. This is short screencast (400kb) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/190203/test.mpeg

Comment: i think problem in ur height or width of ur custom layout.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My problem was located in onMeasure method.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in the XML layout file for the ListView.

Check this-  **ListView Backgrounds: An Optimization**
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html
This can solve your problem.